# Serilog Blackholing logs at startup in ASP.NET core project

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, serilog

I am trying to log a message within the `UseSerilog()` configuration method. `Log` is initially setup using `CreateBootstrapLogger()` and seems to output fine outside of/before `UseSerilog()` is called... once the transition to the config in `UseSerilog()` is complete, it seems to work fine again.

To be more clear, in the second code block, the `_log.Warning(...);` **should print, but does not.**

(Some output and what I've tried so far after all the code.)

Here's Main:

```cs
private static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ConfigureLogger().CreateBootstrapLogger();
    _log = Log.ForContext(typeof(Program));
    
    try
    {
        _log.Information("Starting...");
        await CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().RunAsync();
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        _log.Fatal(e, "Terminating: unhandled exception");
    }
    finally
    {
        _log.Information("Shutting down...");
        Log.CloseAndFlush();
    }
}
```

The `UseSerilog()` method (and the rest of the startup configuration). The log I'm trying to print in inside the `if` statement:

```cs
private static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) => Host
    .CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .ConfigureServices((context, services) =>
    {
        var logConfig = context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging");
        var selectedLogLevel = logConfig.GetValue("Level", defaultValue: LogEventLevel.Information);
        services.AddSingleton(new LoggingLevelSwitch(selectedLogLevel));
    })
    .UseSerilog((context, services, configureLog) =>
    {
        var logConfig = context.Configuration.GetSection("Logging");
        var seqConfig = logConfig.GetSection("Seq");
        var seqEnable = seqConfig.GetValue("Enable", defaultValue: false);
        var seqUrl = seqConfig.GetValue("Url", defaultValue: string.Empty);
        var seqToken = seqConfig.GetValue("Token", defaultValue: string.Empty);
        var logLevel = services.GetRequiredService<LoggingLevelSwitch>();

        if (seqEnable && (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seqUrl) || string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(seqToken)))
        {
            _log.Warning("Seq sink disabled: required parameter empty");
            Console.WriteLine("I'm being hit");
            seqEnable = false;
        }

        configureLog.ConfigureLogger(logLevel, seqEnable, seqUrl, seqToken);
    })
    .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => webBuilder
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel()
        .ConfigureKestrel((context, kestrelOptions) => kestrelOptions
            .Listen(IPAddress.Parse("10.0.0.50"), 5011, listenOptions => listenOptions
                .UseHttps("AspNetDevCert.pfx", context.Configuration["local-cert-password"])
            )
        )
    );
```

The `ConfigureLogger()` and `EnableProductionOnlySinks()` methods:

```cs
private static LoggerConfiguration ConfigureLogger(this LoggerConfiguration config = null,
    LoggingLevelSwitch logLevel = null,
    bool seqEnabled = false,
    string seqUrl = "",
    string seqToken = "",
    string template = LogTemplate)
{
    config ??= new LoggerConfiguration();
    logLevel ??= new LoggingLevelSwitch(LogEventLevel.Debug);
    
    if (seqEnabled && (seqUrl == string.Empty || seqToken == string.Empty))
        throw new ArgumentException($"{nameof(seqUrl)} and/or {nameof(seqToken)} is empty while {nameof(seqEnabled)} is {true}");

    return config
        .Enrich.WithEnvironmentName()
        .Enrich.FromLogContext()
        .Enrich.WithProperty("ProjectName", "PlaylistCopy.Api")
        .MinimumLevel.ControlledBy(logLevel)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft", LogEventLevel.Warning)
        .MinimumLevel.Override("Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime", LogEventLevel.Information)
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.Console(outputTemplate: template))
        .WriteTo.Async(a => a.File(
            new CompactJsonFormatter(),
            "logs/playlist-copy-api-.log",
            rollingInterval: RollingInterval.Day))
        .EnableProductionOnlySinks(seqEnabled, seqUrl, seqToken);
}

private static LoggerConfiguration EnableProductionOnlySinks(this LoggerConfiguration config,
    bool production,
    string seqUrl,
    string seqToken) =>
    production ? config.WriteTo.Seq(seqUrl, apiKey: seqToken) : config;
```

Here's the console sink output (the file sink is identical)

```
[21:09:51 INF] (PlaylistCopy.Api.Program) Starting...
I'm being hit
[21:09:52 INF] (Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) Now listening on: https://10.0.0.50:5011
[21:09:52 INF] (Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) Application started. Press Ctrl+C to shut down.
[21:09:52 INF] (Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) Hosting environment: Production
[21:09:52 INF] (Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) Content root path: [redacted]
[21:09:54 INF] (Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime) Application is shutting down...
[21:09:54 INF] (PlaylistCopy.Api.Program) Shutting down...
```

I've tried using `Task.Delay(5_000)` and `Thread.Sleep(5_000)`, both failed. I tried using `Log.CloseAndFlush()` placed right after the log, this also did not work. I also tired using a the regular `CreateLogger()` in place of `CreateBootstrapLogger()`, but that did not work either. Any suggestions or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

**Edit:**

I found that by setting the `preserveStaticLogger` parameter to `true` in one of the `UseSerilog()` overloads, the log message within `UseSerilog()` is now printed, but I'm not sure how this will fare long-term. According to an old [GitHub issue](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore/issues/105) `preserveStaticLogger` has some unintended side-effects for my purposes, but the main issue is that there are effectively two "source" loggers going around now. The main `Log.Logger` and a `RegisteredLogger` which only asp.net uses. I suppose it is not much of an issue so long as both are configured properly (duplicated configuration) and `CloseAndFlush` is called on both.

**Edit 2:**

Removing the `Async` sinks allowed the `Console` sink to output the log message as expected (without `preserveStaticLogger: false`), but the message is still not found within the `File` sink. This leads me to believe the sinks are not properly flushed... and it's starting to sound a bit more like a bug(?) in the [serilog-extensions-hosting](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-extensions-hosting) package, which [serilog-aspnetcore](https://github.com/serilog/serilog-aspnetcore) depends on.

Comment: Hmmm, sorry but I still wanna ask, what's the error or issue?

Comment: @TinyWang in the second code block, `_log.Warning(...);` should print, but does not. Sorry for not being more explicit; I'll edit the original questions.

Comment: thanks for your reply and, firstly pls see my screenshot to see my configuration and it really print log information. the `_log` in my side is defined like `private static Serilog.ILogger _log;` .And this line `configureLog.ConfigureLogger(logLevel, seqEnable, seqUrl, seqToken);` has error message :`LoggerConfiguration doesn't contain a definition for ConfigureLogger` and I'm afraid you need to provide more details on your installed package. https://i.stack.imgur.com/TB5tp.png

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).